# Avoid permutations when searching for coincident data

Tags: python

I have this data:

```
1,           0.,           0.,        1500.
.
.     
21,           0.,        2000.,        1500.
22,           0.,        2100.,        1500.
```

which I already appended to a list called nodes: nodes[node ID, coord. x, coord. y, coord. z].

Now I want to find the coincident nodes. So I've tried:

```
for data in nodes:
    for data2 in nodes:
        if data2[1]==data[1] and data2[2]==data[2] and data2[3]==data[3] and data[0]<>data2[0]:
            coincident_nodes.append((data[0],data2[0]))
```

what happens is that I get for instance: (31, 32) and (32, 31) and I only want (31, 32) or (32, 31), just one combination.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your algorithm isn't very efficient, but simply replace `data[0]<>data2[0]` with `data[0]<data2[0]` would do it

Comment: `<>` is obsolete. Use `!=` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will be much faster when there are more than a few nodes

```
from collections import defaultdict

nd = defaultdict(list)

for item in nodes:
    nd[tuple(item[1:])].append(item[0])

coincident_nodes = [v for k,v in nd.items() if len(v)>1]
```

Comment: Your code is not easy for me but it made me see that with other codes I didn't got really the results I wanted. For instance i get (31, 32, 125, 360) whereas with other codes I got (31, 32), (31, 125), (31, 360) but also (32, 125), (32, 360) and (125, 360). Great!

Comment: @jpcgandre: gnibbler snippet is actually quite easy to understand, once you see that it works in two steps.  Step 1: build a dictionary which keys are the (x,y,z) coordinates and the value is a list where the id(s) of items with these coordinates are recorded.  Step 2: get from dictionary all values (all lists of coincidences) where the list has more than one ID in it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's OK to have a set at the end, you can do this on the list you generated:

```
>>> a = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (5, 6), (4, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
>>> set([tuple(sorted(e)) for e in a])
set([(1, 2), (5, 6), (3, 4)])
```

Here's another way you can make it unique by removing duplicates:

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(2,1),(3,4),(5,6),(4,3)]
>>> uniq = set()
>>> for e in a:
...   if (e not in uniq) and ((e[1], e[0]) not in uniq):
...     uniq.add(e)
... 
>>> uniq
set([(1, 2), (5, 6), (3, 4)])
```

This assumes there are no duplicates (i.e. if you have `(x, y)`, then you have it at most once). If there are, just make the above like this:

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(2,1),(3,4),(5,6),(4,3),(1,2),(1,2)]
>>> uniq = set()
>>> for e in a:
...   if (e not in uniq) and ((e[1], e[0]) not in uniq):
...     uniq.add(e)
... 
>>> print uniq
set([(1, 2), (5, 6), (3, 4)])
```

Comment: I've already got rid of (x,x) so the first solution is the best for me! Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: If there are duplicates you can use set(a).

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help - see the edit for a shorter set-based solution if that's OK for you.

Comment: be aware that the `for ...: if ... not in uniq` where uniq is a list is O(n^2).  in other words, it will be slow for large amounts of data.  a set-based solution will be more efficient.